# prevent catching a character from a group in regular expression

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm dealing with timecodes. What I'm trying to get is hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds from expressions like **[HH:MM:SS.ms] or [HH:MM:SS]**.

I've tried this:

```
pattern = "\[(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(.(\d+))?\]"
tcs = re.findall(pattern, text.String)
```

and it returns a list of tuples like these:

```
tcs = [('00', '01', '10', '.456', '456'), ...]

# So I can get what I want like this:
h, m, s, _, ms = tcs[0]
```

I don't need the third element in the tuple, the '.456', I'd like to only get the '456'. Is it a way to do that from an expression marked with a '?' (zero or one)?

Comment: Probably just a non-capture group like so `\[(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)(?:\.(\d+))?\]`, note that I also escaped the dot to make it match a literal dot. That being said, while Python is not my forte I can imagine there are other (better?) ways than regex to extract this information.

Comment: Eurêka! Thanks a lot. Better way to express this information? You mean by slicing for example?